# In C, How to use scanf to scan in 1,000,000 ignoring the commas

Tags: c, scanf

In C, what is the best way to ignore the commas when using `scanf` on a number like 1,000,000?

Comment: while (scanf("%4[^,],%4[^,],%79[^,],%d", sem, type, title, &value) == 4) try this out

Comment: I don't know, but maybe chnage the [locale](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locales.html#Locales)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to remove the commas (or any other character you want to skip). One of the easiest (and most flexible) is to simply walk two pointers down the input string shifting all the digits together ignoring the commas. (you must be sure to *nul-terminate* after the final digit).

An example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAXC 25

long xstrtol (char *p, char **ep, int base);

int main (void) {

    char string[MAXC] = "";
    char *rp, *wp;          /* a read pointer and write pointer */
    int c;
    long n = 0;

    rp = wp = string;

    printf ("enter number with ',': ");
    if (!fgets (string, MAXC, stdin)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* work down each char in string, shifting number together */
    while (*rp && (('0' <= *rp && *rp <= '9') || *rp == ',')) {
        if (*rp == ',') { rp++; continue; }     /* skip commas */
        *wp++ = *rp;               /* shift digits together    */
        rp++;
    }
    *wp = 0;   /* nul-terminate */

    if (*rp != '\n') /* flush input buffer */
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}

    printf ("\n string : %s\n", string);
    n = xstrtol (string, &rp, 10);       /* convert string to long */

    printf(" n      : %ld\n\n", n);

    return 0;
}

/** a simple strtol implementation with error checking.
 *  any failed conversion will cause program exit. Adjust
 *  response to failed conversion as required.
 */
long xstrtol (char *p, char **ep, int base)
{
    errno = 0;

    long tmp = strtol (p, ep, base);

    /* Check for various possible errors */
    if ((errno == ERANGE && (tmp == LONG_MIN || tmp == LONG_MAX)) ||
        (errno != 0 && tmp == 0)) {
        perror ("strtol");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (*ep == p) {
        fprintf (stderr, "No digits were found\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

(*note:* `xstrtol` simply provides error checking on the conversion of `string` to `long`)

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/nwithcomma
enter number with ',': 1,234,567

 string : 1234567
 n      : 1234567
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions. You can check against `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` if you want to cast the result to `int`, but it is just as easy to leave the answer as a `long`.

**As a Function**

As pointed out, it would be far more useful as a function. You can move the code to a simple conversion function, and adjust the main code as follows:

```
...
#define MAXC 25

long fmtstrtol (char *s);
long xstrtol (char *p, char **ep, int base);

int main (void) {

    char string[MAXC] = "";

    printf ("enter number with ',': ");
    if (!fgets (string, MAXC, stdin)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf(" number : %ld\n\n", fmtstrtol (string));

    return 0;
}

/* convert comma formatted string to long */
long fmtstrtol (char *s)
{
    if (!s || !*s) {
        fprintf (stderr, "fmtstrtol() error: invalid string.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *rp, *wp;  /* read pointer, write pointer */
    int c;

    rp = wp = s;

    while (*rp && (('0' <= *rp && *rp <= '9') || *rp == ',')) {
        if (*rp == ',') { rp++; continue; }
        *wp++ = *rp;
        rp++;
    }
    *wp = 0;

    if (*rp != '\n') /* flush input buffer */
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}

    return xstrtol (s, &rp, 10);
}
...
```

Comment: Why a complete working program? It could be a function.

Comment: True, it was just a top down example that I didn't reformat into a function `:(`

Comment: @haccks - laziness corrected - function provided `:)`

Comment: Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 14):

I would say the best way is to *not* use `scanf` for this. At least not using any number formats.

Instead read it as a string, then remove the commas, and finally [convert to a number](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).